# python regular expression group matching with anti '|'

Tags: python, regex

Here is my code:

```
import re

p = re.compile('(?P<name>[^|]*)|(?P<desc>[^|]*)')
m = p.match('jack|a good boy')
name = m.group('name')
desc = m.group('desc')
print name  # jack
print desc  # None
```

How can I get the desc after the '|'?

Comment: Does this even want for regexes? What's wrong with splitting the string?

Comment: I don't want to use **split**.it doesn't work well sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a `|` you must escape it. Otherwise your pattern would match either first or last group. But, not the both.

```
import re

p = re.compile('(?P<name>[^|]*)\|(?P<desc>[^|]*)')
m = p.match('jack|a good boy')
name = m.group('name')
desc = m.group('desc')
print name  # jack
print desc  # a good boy
```

*Note I've changed your piece of code a bit. Just escaped `|` to `\|`.*

Comment: uh..I see. '|' means OR in python regex.It must be escaped.thanks @Cylian

Comment: Regardless of RegEx flavors ``|`` means ``OR``.